# Optimal shape for Multiprocessing Pool.map in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Say you have a matrix of MxN elems (nested list.) And you want to parallelize operations; so your choices are parallelize by row or parallelize by column. Suppose that data/operations are independent and require only the value of matrix[i][j].

Depending on size of M & N, what is the best way to distribute?

My thinking is that the overhead cost of spinning up a process is nontrivial, so you should distribute based on min(M,N)

Eg if there are 1000 rows and 30 columns, it's better to distribute based on columns (less times needed to spin up a process.) Conversely, if there are 30 rows and 1000 columns, distribute by rows.

Is this thinking sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this depends on what the work is, and how long does it take for one "work unit" to be executed, for example if you are just summing two matrices then you don't need to use multiprocessing at all, and in general there will never be a "one size fits all", the only solid answer you can get is **always benchmark to find out**.

if you have a `1000x30` matrix then you have `30_000` tasks, splitting them to 1000 tasks or 30 tasks doesn't make sense either way.

if each task takes equal time you could distribute them equally to your workers, flatten the array and use [numpy.array_split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html#numpy.array_split) to split it into chunks the number of your workers and pass them, this will minimize the serialization overhead, and make sure each core does nearly equal work.

to account for unequal work or unfair scheduling from the OS you may want to split the tasks to a multiple (4-16) of the number of workers and setting `chunksize=1` in `pool.map`, this will allow a worker to steal some work from another one if it finishes its work first, at the cost of slightly higher serialization overhead.

the optimal number of workers is also obtainable by benchmarking, but if you expect a variable number of tasks, then you should define a certain chunksize, for example you will spawn 1 worker for each 500 tasks, and up to the number of cores on the CPU, again, you should obtain that number from **benchmarking your code**.

Comment: If I flatten the matrix, pool.map should automatically be able to infer the number of cores available and divide the number tasks assigned to each evenly, right? (This might not be equal work as some tasks might be more computationally expensive)

Comment: @jbuddy_13 not really, the distribution of `pool.map` is okay, it's fast enough that most people don't bother changing it, but it is far from optimal, for unequal work you may want to manually distribute it to a multiple of your number of workers, for example 8-16 times the number of workers (using `split_array` and `chunksize=1`), this will allow a worker to steal the work of another if the other worker takes too much time, but at the cost of higher serialization overhead.